# Using a dictionary to control the flow of methods

Tags: python, methods, dictionary

I have a class Population that contains several method.

According to an input I want the run the method on an instance of the class `Population` in a given order.

To be a bit more accurate in what I am trying to achieve is quite the same than using is something like that:

```
stuff = input(" enter stuff ")

dico = {'stuff1':functionA, 'stuff2':functionC, 'stuff3':functionB, 'stuff4':functionD}

dico[stuff]()
```

Except that the functionA, functionB etc... are methods and not functions:

```
order_type = 'a'
class Population (object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def method1 (self):
        self.a = self.a*2
        return self

    def method2 (self):
        self.a += 2
        return self

    def method3 (self,b):
        self.a = self.a + b
        return self

if order_type=='a':
    order = {1:method1, 2:method2, 3:method3}
elif order_type=='b':
    order = {1:method2, 2:method1, 3:method3}
else :
    order = {1:method3, 2:method2, 3:method1}

my_pop = Population(3)

while iteration < 100:
    iteration +=1
    for i in range(len(order)):
        method_to_use = order[i]
        my_pop.method_to_use() # But obviously it doesn't work!
```

Hope I've made my question clear enough!
Note that one of my method need two arguments

Comment: @Keyser Yes you're right I could use a list as well but it won't change much to the problem I had

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. But I now realize a second problem with your solutions. What if I need to add a second argument for one of the three methods only? I updated my post to examplify my question.

Comment: Well I can do this with a if else statement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the instance explicitly as first argument:

```
method_to_use = order[i]
method_to_use(my_pop)
```

Full working code:

```
order_type = 'a'
class Population (object):
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def method1 (self):
        self.a = self.a*2
        return self

    def method2 (self):
        self.a += 2
        return self

    def method3 (self):
        self.a = 0
        return self

if order_type=='a':
    order = [Population.method1, Population.method2, Population.method3]
elif order_type=='b':
    order = [Population.method2, Population.method1, Population.method3]
else :
    order = [Population.method3, Population.method2, Population.method1]

my_pop = Population(3)

while iteration < 100:
    iteration +=1
    for method_to_use in order:
        method_to_use(my_pop)
```

If you want to pass more than one argument, simply use the `*args` syntax:

```
if order_type=='a':
    order = [Population.method1, Population.method2, Population.method3]
    arguments = [(), (), (the_argument,)]
elif order_type=='b':
    order = [Population.method2, Population.method1, Population.method3]
    arguments = [(), (), (the_argument,)]
else :
    order = [Population.method3, Population.method2, Population.method1]
    arguments = [(the_argument, ), (), ()]

my_pop = Population(3)

while iteration < 100:
    iteration +=1
    for method_to_use, args in zip(order, arguments):
        method_to_use(my_pop, *args)
```

The `()` is an empty tuple, hence `*args` will expand to no additional arguments, while `(the_argument,)` is a 1-element tuple that will pass the argument to the method.

Comment: Thks you all for your help! What if I need to pass for method 3 (but not to other methods) a second argument then?

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr`:

```
order = {1:'method1', 2:'method2', 3:'method3'} #values are strings
...
method_to_use = order[i]
getattr(mypop, method_to_use)()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
from operator import methodcaller
method_to_use = methodcaller('method' + str(i))
method_to_use(my_pop)
```